# How to set color effect on image in camera2 API?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm working on small android camera application that opens CameraPreview on start using Camera2 API.i want to set color effects.

Comment: may be this will help you https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus

Comment: @SunilChaudhary it's work for me thanks.

Comment: greate to hear that